Универсальный слушатель по дефолту
onpointerleave - срабатывает когда наводим на элемент
onpointerenter - наоборот
Вопрос в том, есть ли один слушатель, который скажет когда навели, а когда увели...
Второй вопрос, что лучше использовать.
Есть слушатели который дают сигнал когда курсор попадает именно на этот элемент, другие, когда курсор так же попадает на дочерние элементы. То есть есть слушатели, которые вешаем на родителя и они не срабатывают если курсор на дочернем элементе...
Есть ли между ними разница, в скорости срабатывания, нагружают ли больше браузер пользователя?

onpointerleave - срабатывает когда наводим на элемент onpointerenter - наоборот - Нет.

Вопрос в том, есть ли один слушатель, который скажет когда навели, а когда увели... - Чем эта строка отличается от предыдущего?

Есть слушатели который дают сигнал когда курсор попадает именно на этот элемент, другие, когда курсор так же попадает на дочерние элементы. То есть есть слушатели, которые вешаем на родителя и они не срабатывают если курсор на дочернем элементе... - В браузере работает погружение и всплытие событий, благодаря чему любые события проходят по дереву вверх и вниз. Отдельных таких событий нет
